# How to retrieve records with max `delivery date` for each `order number`

Tags: mysql, join, maxdate

I am looking to retrieve all the the records and columns by order number of a table `TEST` where for a each order number the `MAX` of the column `orderDeliveryDate` is equal to yesterday. The following code does not work:

```
SELECT  T.* 
FROM    TEST T
    INNER JOIN(
            SELECT orderNum, MAX(orderDeliveryDate) AS maxDeliveryDate
            FROM TEST
            GROUP BY orderNum) MX
        ON T.orderNum= MX.orderNum
        AND T.orderDeliveryDate = MX.maxDeliveryDate
        AND MX.maxDeliveryDate = DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST 
WHERE ORDERNUM IN 
    (SELECT ORDERNUM, MAX(orderDeliveryDate)
     FROM TEST GROUP BY ORDERNUM 
     HAVING DATE(MAX(orderDeliveryDate)) = DATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
```

The guess I'm making is orderDeliveryDate is a DateTime, so converting it to a Date will fix your problem. Your original query would work with the conversion to Date, I think mine is just a little more straightforward.

Comment: You need to at least group by orderNum

Comment: If it's a date, your query should work. If it has a time in it, it won't. In other words 2015-09-11 08.00.00.000 is not equal to 2015-09-11 09.00.00.000

Comment: Yes it is a date. The query does not work: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.3480 sec)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the column to a date before comparing, and for an efficiency move the test into the sub query:

```
SELECT  T.* 
FROM TEST T
JOIN(
    SELECT orderNum, DATE(MAX(orderDeliveryDate)) AS maxDeliveryDate
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY orderNum
    HAVING DATE(MAX(orderDeliveryDate)) = DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ) MX
    ON T.orderNum= MX.orderNum
    AND DATE(T.orderDeliveryDate) = MX.maxDeliveryDate
```

Comment: Hi Bohemian - it does not yield any result. I notice you've switch to JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Comment: @ArnaudMartinn JOIN *is* INNER JOIN. They are identical - "INNER" is optional and has no effect when coded

Comment: the code does not yield the expected result: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.1572 sec)

Comment: Is there data matching yesterday (considering it is currently the weekend)?